# Как сделать прокрутку элементов без потери функционала

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Впервые сел за HTML, скачал шаблон https://www.tooplate.com/live/2086_multi_color

ссылка https://html-templates.info/fotografiya/yarkij-gotovyj-html-css-shablon-sajta-galerei-fotografij-multi-color-2023-skachajte-besplatno

И возникла проблема с тем, что не понимаю как сделать так, чтобы в этом шаблоне по нажатию на картинку открывалась другая страница, а не второй уровень галереи

Я долго возился с кодом и найдя стоки `<div class="tm-img-gallery gallery-one">`  и удалив её, всё получилось. Но при этом, в шаблоне пропала возможность прокручивать галерею.

Как мне можно выполнить задачу в этой ситуации?